# NX how to pass arguments to target dependency

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have the project config set in the `package.json` as below:

```json
"nx": {
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "outputs": [
        "{projectRoot}/dist"
      ]
    },
    "build-site": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "build"
      ],
      "outputs": [
        "{projectRoot}/fractal/build"
      ]
    },
    "bundlesize": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "build"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pass an argument to the `build` target it depends on.

`nx run-many --target=build-site --all -- --foo=bar`

This does not seem to get passed down to the `build` target. Is there any way to do this?

[EDIT]

I use npm scripts (in package.json) as targets and have target dependencies defined with Nx like below.

```json
{
  "name": "project-a",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "build-site": "gulp buildFractal"
  },
  "nx": {
    "build-site": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "build"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

And then I run `nx run-many --target=build-site --all`. However, the issue is that I want to pass a flag to the dependent `build` target which does not appear to work when I do `nx run-many --target=build-site --all -- --foo=bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dependsOn` can be configured with a object instead of the shorthand:

```
"dependsOn": [{"projects": "self", "target": "build", "params": "forward"}],
```

Then the params will get forwarded-
Ref: https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration#dependson